# kotlin.time.Duration and java reflection

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

It seems I've encountered a weird problem with interaction of java reflection API (particularly, [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and [kotlin.time.Duration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/). It looks like Java Reflection fails to determine method return type for `kotlin.time.Duration`. Consider the following example:

```
@file:JvmName("Main")
package org.test.kotlin.time.duration

import java.lang.reflect.Proxy
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.seconds

@ExperimentalTime
interface I {
    fun getNullableDuration(): Duration? = 1.seconds
    fun getRange(): IntRange = 1..3
    fun getDuration(): Duration = 1.seconds
}

class IC: I

inline fun <reified T> T.sampleProxy(): T = sampleProxy(T::class.java)

fun <T> sampleProxy(c: Class<T>): T {
    return c.cast(Proxy.newProxyInstance(c.classLoader, arrayOf(c)) { _, method, _ ->
        println("[proxy] ${method.declaringClass.name}::${method.name} return type is ${method.returnType}")
        when (method.name) {
            "getNullableDuration", "getDuration" -> 1.seconds
            "getRange"                           -> 0..1
            else                                 -> TODO("method ${method.name} isn't handled yet")
        }
    })
}

fun main() {
    val v: I = IC()
    println("I::getNullableDuration() return type is ${v::getNullableDuration.returnType}")
    v.sampleProxy().getNullableDuration()
    println("I::getRange() return type is ${v::getRange.returnType}")
    v.sampleProxy().getRange()
    println("I::getDuration() return type is ${v::getDuration.returnType}")
    v.sampleProxy().getDuration()
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
I::getNullableDuration() return type is kotlin.time.Duration?
[proxy] org.test.kotlin.time.duration.I::getNullableDuration return type is class kotlin.time.Duration
I::getRange() return type is kotlin.ranges.IntRange
[proxy] org.test.kotlin.time.duration.I::getRange return type is class kotlin.ranges.IntRange
I::getDuration() return type is kotlin.time.Duration
[proxy] org.test.kotlin.time.duration.I::getDuration return type is double
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.time.Duration cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (kotlin.time.Duration is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Double is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getDuration(Unknown Source)
    at org.test.kotlin.time.duration.Main.main(main.kt:38)
    at org.test.kotlin.time.duration.Main.main(main.kt)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As one can see, inside `sampleProxy` return types for `getNullableDuration()` and `getRange()` are determined correctly (`kotlin.time.Duration?` expectedly becomes `kotlin.time.Duration`), while `getDuration()` suddenly becomes a method returning `double` and the cast from kotlin.time.Duration to double on return from the method fails with the exception.

What could be a reason for the problem? How can I workaround it?

My environment:

- OpenJDK 11.0.6+10
- Kotlin 1.3.71
- Linux/x86-64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Duration`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) is an [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html) class for `double`.

This means:

- the Kotlin compiler will use `double` where it is possible
- where it is not a wrapper type will be used instead

From the [representation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html#representation) section:

> In generated code, the Kotlin compiler keeps a wrapper for each *inline* class. Inline class instances can be represented at runtime either as wrappers or as the underlying type.
>
> The Kotlin compiler will prefer using underlying types instead of wrappers to produce the most performant and optimized code. **However, sometimes it is necessary to keep wrappers around. As a rule of thumb, inline classes are boxed whenever they are used as another type.**

In the provided example:

- `getNullableDuration` returns `Duration?` which means boxing the value (see the example in the [representation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html#representation) section of Kotlin documentation.
- `getDuration` returns just `Duration` which allows compiler to use the underlying type, `double` instead of the wrapper.
- the line `"getNullableDuration", "getDuration" -> 1.seconds` returns a wrapper instead of underlying type because the [`InvocationHandler#invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Method,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) returns an Object, which does not allow the compiler to use the underlying type.

That's why the `ClassCastException` thrown. The compiled `getDuration` method returns a `double`, but the proxy will always return `Duration`.

Here is how the `IC` looks like when decompiled to Java:

```java
public final class IC implements I {
   @Nullable
   public Duration getNullableDuration() {
      return I.DefaultImpls.getNullableDuration(this);
   }

   @NotNull
   public IntRange getRange() {
      return I.DefaultImpls.getRange(this);
   }

      // vvvvvvvvvv here is the double
   public double getDuration() {
      return I.DefaultImpls.getDuration(this);
   }
}
```

#### Workarounds

The most straightforward one is to use a *nullable* type

Another one is to return `double` for the `getDuration` method:

```kotlin
when (method.name) {
     "getNullableDuration" -> 1.seconds
     "getDuration" -> 1.0
     "getRange"-> 0..1
      else -> TODO("method ${method.name} isn't handled yet")
}
```

---

Please note that both the time api and `inline` classes are *experimential*